# Problemas con un header con sticky y un aside con nav

Tags: html, css, css3, nav, sticky

Tengo un `header` con `sticky` para que siempre me aparezca mientras bajo por la pagina y tengo un `aside` con enlaces internos.

Cuando le doy `click` a uno y la pagina baja hasta un `article`, el `header` con `sticky` me tapa la parte de arriba del `article` (*el h3 y una parte del p*).

Quisiera que al darle a un enlace del `aside` me baje hasta la seccion correspondiente y el `header` quede un poco más arriba del encabezado para que no me lo tape.

¿Cómo puedo arreglarlo? (Prefiero poner el header con sticky que con fixed)

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    background: lightgray;
}
/* Encabezado */
.sticky{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

.sticky__header{
    background: #020230;
    height: 70px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
header img{
    height: 50px;
}
header a{
    color: #1cbeda;
}

.sticky__nav{
    background: #000;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.sticky__nav a{
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.sticky__nav a:hover{
    text-decoration: solid underline;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
}
/* Cuerpo */
main{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 6px;
}
section{
    margin-right: 100px;
    width: 80%;
}

aside{
    padding: 5px;
    height: 400px;
    position: sticky;
    top: 170px;
    width: 20%;
    overflow: auto;
    margin: 0 10px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

nav h2{
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: 500;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
.navigation__ul{
    border-left: 1px solid #a1a0a0;
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0px;
}
.navigation__ul-li{
    padding: 15px;
}

.navigation__ul-li a{
    color: #4e4e4e;
}

.navigation__ul-li a:hover{
    color: #0085f2;
}

/* Pie de pagina */
footer{
    background: #020230;
    height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 30px;
}


*::-webkit-scrollbar{
width: 10px;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track{
background: transparent;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
background-color: #808080cb;
border-radius: 10px;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover{
background: #5e5c5c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-co">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ImN3cWvQ-hLJEbSI-l-aWQAAAA?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Maquetado</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="sticky">
        <header class="sticky__header">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ImN3cWvQ-hLJEbSI-l-aWQAAAA?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain" alt="icono-web"></a>
            <a href="index.html"><h1>Guía de la web</h1></a>
        </header>
        <nav class="sticky__nav">
            <a href="#html">HTML</a>
            <a href="#css">CSS</a>
            <a href="#js">JAVASCRIPT</a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <h2>Recursos para desarrolladores &#128187</h2>
    <main>
        <section>
            <article id="html">
                <h3>html</h3>
                <p>Es el componente más básico de la Web. Define el significado y la estructura del contenido web.Es un estándar que sirve de referencia del software que conecta con la elaboración de páginas web en sus diferentes versiones, define una estructura básica y un código (denominado código HTML) para la definición de contenido de una página web, como texto, imágenes, videos, juegos, entre otros.
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nihil quia velit ea ut magni assumenda. Culpa adipisci dolores facilis ipsam! Unde fuga porro error labore assumenda soluta earum dolore?
                    Natus consectetur quo esse voluptatibus unde neque deserunt perspiciatis cum ab mollitia consequatur, fugit corporis voluptatem! In aliquid totam, nostrum voluptate sunt libero necessitatibus accusantium veniam nihil error, placeat magnam!
                    Ullam, accusamus error! Aliquam at nobis exercitationem cumque ut atque sequi nihil ex debitis provident odit, iusto molestiae expedita enim. Optio quos magnam debitis veniam amet quas dolores quaerat possimus.
                    Facilis, harum obcaecati sint tenetur corporis explicabo ducimus consectetur labore incidunt, eligendi hic voluptatibus exercitationem ex, ad beatae architecto? Atque rem reprehenderit voluptate non fugiat numquam iure, exercitationem harum sapiente.
                    Sint, doloribus harum. Mollitia voluptate accusantium maxime, debitis quis laborum similique fugiat aut eos quod expedita exercitationem sequi delectus. Voluptate iusto error architecto consectetur aperiam modi nesciunt aspernatur totam cumque. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quod necessitatibus suscipit dignissimos, quas quia exercitationem natus. Officia eos esse magni, illum mollitia rem, illo eum id aliquid quis facere.
                    In incidunt asperiores nulla iusto temporibus! Quidem illum eum, cum expedita aliquam rerum molestiae. Nemo autem odio error odit officia illum beatae maxime. Ducimus ex rem repellat atque quibusdam officia?
                    Ex, amet vero accusantium ullam dignissimos, voluptatum quia autem voluptatibus voluptates obcaecati odio soluta assumenda cupiditate! Cupiditate, eveniet! Ab fugiat voluptate suscipit explicabo ducimus saepe quibusdam sed, id sequi non!
                    Iusto eius eos odio ipsum vero ducimus quam! Sit harum, necessitatibus voluptatem tenetur ut voluptatibus assumenda libero, officiis neque, praesentium sint totam id minus quisquam. Delectus minus nihil ratione error.
                    Ut earum accusantium aliquam laudantium! Error, consequatur corporis? Voluptatem, quaerat. Quos, iure odit non, maxime repellat minima blanditiis minus sapiente ipsum quod id nostrum quidem culpa ea! Quia, perspiciatis distinctio! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem eius ullam, illum quam rem voluptate aut quae dicta quis reprehenderit animi fugiat at soluta, natus cumque molestias laborum magnam quaerat!
                    Velit blanditiis aspernatur quos delectus! Expedita ipsa quisquam quidem ipsum libero animi error nihil eius veritatis itaque, excepturi saepe dolor quos cum maiores vitae ut culpa? Voluptas est ad ab!
                    Aut voluptas, quas blanditiis aliquid, repudiandae impedit nesciunt neque sunt nam at atque aperiam corrupti voluptatum possimus necessitatibus? Possimus architecto omnis atque dignissimos labore eius provident consequuntur ab adipisci itaque.
                    Officiis facere odit cumque at harum, eos expedita aspernatur consequatur obcaecati laborum fugiat. Sunt quod iste tenetur harum quas pariatur amet, magnam alias iure fugiat dolorum sapiente reiciendis placeat. Vel?
                    Ullam facere, neque ipsum ratione facilis in laudantium quo dolorum iusto, consequuntur, voluptatem laborum mollitia quibusdam. Impedit, incidunt! Quasi neque doloremque quae id mollitia sint optio, aliquam veritatis corrupti veniam. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi tenetur incidunt ratione illo, odit omnis consequatur ut ducimus placeat excepturi repellat. Quas, magnam! Sint, eius sunt laudantium similique suscipit totam.
                    Repudiandae, temporibus, sequi sint earum recusandae perferendis quia, nihil quaerat placeat optio unde modi amet. Totam aliquid tenetur eos optio explicabo quia saepe eius! Sed facere ea labore amet blanditiis?
                    Omnis magnam enim temporibus dicta doloribus excepturi tempora voluptas consequuntur ipsa assumenda? Aspernatur possimus dolor, sapiente quod repudiandae harum natus quidem voluptates dignissimos dolore id explicabo minima reprehenderit dolores iste!
                    Quia doloremque sed iste dignissimos, natus iure obcaecati rem impedit ipsum fugit mollitia corrupti ratione veritatis quidem nihil quos eum quae dolorum deleniti voluptatem quod earum omnis? Quia, aut laborum.
                    Autem debitis soluta exercitationem, iste iusto ipsa quae temporibus a? Ut maxime cupiditate adipisci? Provident quasi assumenda officia corrupti, excepturi commodi qui repellendus facere distinctio cum recusandae quaerat eius et?
                    In molestiae quidem quam est, vitae excepturi corporis non sapiente laborum, unde quis sint placeat sit aliquid. Rem expedita ullam nostrum repudiandae possimus, ducimus maiores, natus quidem dolor iure ipsa.
                    Ipsum quidem sequi cupiditate officia excepturi voluptatibus adipisci vero deserunt esse minus, expedita libero nihil aut nostrum doloremque incidunt ab praesentium delectus ipsa. Modi iusto eius deserunt. Vel, soluta magni!</span>
                </p>
            </article>
            <article id="css">
                <h3>css</h3>
                <p>Es un lenguaje de diseño gráfico para definir y crear la presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en un lenguaje de marcado.Es muy usado para establecer el diseño visual de los documentos web, e interfaces de usuario escritas en HTML o XHTML; el lenguaje puede ser aplicado a cualquier documento XML, incluyendo XHTML, SVG, XUL, RSS, etcétera. Junto con HTML y JavaScript, CSS es una tecnología usada por muchos sitios web para crear páginas visualmente atractivas, interfaces de usuario para aplicaciones web y GUIs para muchas aplicaciones móviles
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique aperiam facilis, excepturi reprehenderit, distinctio dolor temporibus qui magnam et alias explicabo eligendi libero. Culpa at nulla architecto veniam omnis perferendis.
                    Ex nostrum eligendi sunt mollitia amet, inventore pariatur impedit, voluptatibus consectetur quae a placeat, repellendus iure velit dolorem excepturi atque id voluptatem porro eum quia accusantium ullam! Iure, quod nemo.
                    Et libero commodi illo tempora omnis perspiciatis fuga impedit ducimus porro laborum! Magnam soluta eligendi quam itaque aut incidunt suscipit, odio numquam inventore blanditiis tempore id, officiis nostrum! Modi, ipsa?
                    Dolorum incidunt aperiam ducimus, nesciunt exercitationem ad sequi dignissimos natus enim aliquid nisi repellendus facere autem repudiandae mollitia expedita velit dolorem eligendi harum molestias odio quos? Illum itaque possimus voluptates?
                    Praesentium suscipit laborum nihil animi, reiciendis quisquam magnam repudiandae soluta ad hic obcaecati quos dolores nemo quia debitis quo tenetur aut error necessitatibus ab architecto sed deleniti illo eligendi. Numquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga totam repellendus obcaecati error, placeat sequi quisquam perferendis nostrum sed nobis esse et enim, quam porro alias excepturi. Maxime, praesentium temporibus.
                    Labore ex cum a aliquam reprehenderit architecto doloremque possimus ab, dolorem rem doloribus. Sapiente fugiat numquam maxime repellat, aut animi, ab fugit dicta illo ipsam, similique recusandae saepe qui minus!
                    Soluta debitis perferendis dignissimos distinctio eaque saepe repellendus eius quas aliquid ea! Magnam fugit perspiciatis magni beatae minima, ratione sit ipsam itaque omnis! Facilis ipsum nostrum, atque similique quasi sed!
                    Nulla, placeat, aut excepturi accusamus quidem non eaque commodi facilis possimus aspernatur eos tempora, minus in. Molestias non laborum laboriosam qui doloribus? Qui vero iure totam nemo ipsum, laboriosam corporis!
                    Veniam, voluptatibus error molestias dignissimos aut tenetur, porro aliquam rem sit, nobis voluptates vel facilis harum illum enim id! Repellat alias architecto aspernatur vel facilis quam debitis corrupti quaerat facere! Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores neque perferendis dolores natus expedita voluptatum dolor, amet delectus reprehenderit, dicta, cumque deleniti laboriosam nemo similique necessitatibus iure architecto! Perspiciatis, illo!
                    Corporis, sapiente. Earum minus deleniti quasi natus laudantium sit, enim nihil totam consectetur. Magnam ratione impedit doloremque asperiores sit laudantium at sunt nostrum. Itaque ipsum mollitia cumque. Odit, doloribus eligendi?
                    Ipsa nisi, sint sed excepturi voluptatum soluta ea tempore harum nostrum eos explicabo eligendi error quae cum numquam dolorem veniam fugiat iste inventore assumenda. Asperiores nisi vero quos alias suscipit!
                    Tempora non necessitatibus temporibus nemo obcaecati iste asperiores dicta rem soluta aliquid ullam expedita excepturi sint placeat sit ipsum corporis, at numquam repellendus, laudantium blanditiis in omnis. Placeat, quos quas?
                    Ullam nulla molestiae eveniet modi voluptates rerum doloremque assumenda sint dolores nihil, eum voluptate beatae numquam corporis obcaecati minima architecto molestias quidem autem saepe porro pariatur, veritatis consequatur. Ab, placeat? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, tempora qui voluptas, dolores quos ratione atque laboriosam doloribus id facilis officiis similique. Distinctio esse consequuntur porro, minima earum expedita quia.
                    Deleniti non tenetur ab, possimus reprehenderit soluta accusamus libero laudantium sint consequatur numquam. Adipisci quia assumenda consequuntur impedit, quae cupiditate libero, nihil ea illo earum eum fuga saepe odit! Aliquid.
                    Placeat corporis quam quaerat doloremque unde repellendus dolor natus rem porro ipsa nisi est esse dignissimos quas, corrupti officia quia quisquam odit voluptatibus quod. Veniam ut quo hic dolores nesciunt.
                    Officia quas accusantium, vitae animi, dicta quibusdam quae dolore quam, ipsa molestias quod unde itaque totam error? Veniam hic necessitatibus aliquam odio ex, esse debitis eaque repudiandae. A, temporibus inventore?
                    Eligendi praesentium non voluptatum modi molestias illo dolorum. Odio voluptatibus eligendi placeat tempora repudiandae unde odit facere nemo ipsa corporis? Dolore doloribus vero vitae labore placeat dolor amet culpa molestiae.
                    Molestiae inventore, eaque aliquam id quas maxime nemo, quisquam blanditiis voluptatibus, nostrum repellendus. Perspiciatis harum tempora quos inventore, ducimus aut eum labore perferendis necessitatibus nostrum enim! Asperiores, libero! Eligendi, earum?
                    Cupiditate excepturi dolorem consequuntur delectus facere, ad vel odio beatae soluta! Officiis perferendis cumque impedit minima sint laboriosam quo repudiandae totam saepe ex? Tenetur, porro unde consectetur accusantium quaerat itaque!</span>
                </p>
            </article>
            <article id="javascript">
                <h3>JavaScript</h3>
                <p>Es un lenguaje de programación interpretado, dialecto del estándar ECMAScript. Se define como orientado a objetos, basado en prototipos, imperativo, débilmente tipado y dinámico. Se utiliza principalmente del lado del cliente, implementado como parte de un navegador web permitiendo mejoras en la interfaz de usuario y páginas web dinámicas y JavaScript del lado del servidor.
                    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum praesentium expedita nemo. A voluptatem facilis veniam accusantium ut hic iusto quidem est rerum, pariatur tempore maxime cum iure quo omnis?
                    Nesciunt aliquid repellendus corporis doloribus maiores nulla numquam, maxime impedit velit vitae nam voluptatem id fugiat totam qui optio commodi amet non corrupti quisquam voluptates consectetur, illum praesentium? Excepturi, natus!
                    Minima obcaecati a perspiciatis libero rem, ad deserunt porro, molestiae ab, at doloribus accusamus aspernatur veniam tempora odit praesentium id. Fugiat saepe impedit ipsam obcaecati corrupti delectus at sequi nemo!
                    Culpa voluptas id repellendus voluptatum et minus deleniti sunt adipisci suscipit atque! Exercitationem praesentium voluptate rerum hic facere, inventore unde sed dolorum assumenda odit quos quibusdam ratione impedit harum. Cum?
                    Nostrum eaque aut atque placeat doloribus maxime unde, ducimus nam quaerat id corporis, reiciendis nulla! Excepturi harum quisquam corporis odit quo? Cupiditate illo dolore accusantium ab quos repellat quo aperiam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque harum aliquid ex nesciunt enim ad qui incidunt provident adipisci, ratione perferendis, ipsa tenetur, dignissimos odio cupiditate unde tempora labore quae.
                    Architecto numquam alias ullam repellendus, adipisci officia impedit facilis dicta et! Voluptates aperiam magni ad a enim, aspernatur quisquam corrupti architecto fugiat quia iure minima tenetur aliquid optio. Cum, voluptates!
                    Neque obcaecati asperiores deleniti sequi sapiente voluptatem expedita provident amet facere omnis qui eos, hic tenetur ducimus culpa odit, voluptatum aperiam adipisci quas nesciunt perferendis voluptates? Unde animi debitis ullam?
                    Quis temporibus nobis possimus nemo voluptatum odio! Maxime rerum neque odio ducimus natus fugiat animi expedita, explicabo quaerat ipsum nemo aperiam laudantium quos dignissimos odit quae ullam doloribus fuga aliquam.
                    Sunt debitis labore fugiat recusandae neque amet odit tempore sed aliquam commodi doloremque at provident laudantium voluptas, quasi aut laboriosam placeat aperiam. Illum modi, minus repudiandae explicabo iure distinctio eaque. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit nulla iste earum perspiciatis similique iure dolorum ad officiis ratione consectetur doloribus temporibus, explicabo, delectus, dicta eveniet eos in odit expedita.
                    Aut blanditiis perspiciatis ipsum, rem temporibus hic debitis possimus repellendus esse dolores delectus sapiente animi sed qui, neque sint tenetur, consequuntur eum sequi odit? Eum tenetur possimus accusantium corporis officiis!
                    A molestiae expedita, id officia ipsum aliquam in nemo quibusdam sit. Repellendus fugit ullam mollitia tempora adipisci impedit molestias tenetur harum quasi quae, cum ipsam quos, itaque error minus a!
                    Voluptate sit corrupti magni fuga voluptatum autem numquam vel repudiandae voluptatibus, totam modi! Accusantium ut nam alias error explicabo odit, magni eveniet laboriosam enim earum doloremque dolorum libero, nemo odio.
                    Reprehenderit aspernatur fuga aliquam facere, reiciendis minus tempora blanditiis sed, expedita optio mollitia nostrum nam iste sunt eaque dolor sint saepe illum magni. Dicta eos culpa minus ab quos autem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ea explicabo odit culpa est minima ipsum eius dolores esse doloremque, libero, sint totam iste voluptatem, cupiditate voluptates temporibus optio quos vero?
                    Debitis, error. Odit, deserunt. Tempora obcaecati consequatur nulla quaerat harum placeat dolor! Modi, beatae? Cumque adipisci explicabo ea autem odio possimus fugit vero! Fuga velit beatae totam, molestias aperiam voluptate!
                    Tempore quisquam rerum cum magnam hic ratione accusantium laudantium cumque excepturi molestiae! Aut labore repellendus earum quos, eos voluptate dignissimos! Debitis impedit sint, repudiandae ab excepturi laboriosam quasi voluptatum dolore!
                    Quasi accusantium laudantium error aut tempore nisi atque provident corporis, et doloremque a harum in! Excepturi, nisi necessitatibus quo reprehenderit earum magni, molestiae laboriosam totam ea reiciendis consequuntur nemo cumque.
                    Nihil voluptas quod unde aspernatur. Illo minus delectus hic dolore dolores. Qui quae dolorem, ad recusandae magnam, odit nam perferendis libero, et ratione asperiores illum voluptates nobis vitae eius natus?
                    Consectetur repudiandae earum mollitia, dicta id facilis dolorum minus dignissimos laborum temporibus, aliquid et dolores similique magni ab commodi! Est, facere officia similique reiciendis asperiores odio magnam deleniti dolorem animi.
                    Similique facere eius, a velit voluptatum, minus qui sapiente, culpa laudantium assumenda dolorem. Quo repudiandae quia accusantium tenetur labore pariatur vel minima. Distinctio placeat accusantium voluptatibus. Officiis eveniet possimus magnam.</span>
                </p>
            </article>
        </section>
    
        <aside>
            <nav>
                <h2>En este articulo</h2>
                <div class="navigation">
                    <ul class="navigation__ul">
                        <li class="navigation__ul-li"><a href="#html">HTML</a></li>
                        <li class="navigation__ul-li"><a href="#css">CSS</a></li>
                        <li class="navigation__ul-li"><a href="#javascript">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </aside>
    </main>

    <footer>
            <p>Esta pagina es una prueba</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En el `nav` tenes un error. El `a` que utilizas para ir a `Javascript` debería ser `<a href="#javascript">JAVASCRIPT</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Necesitas aplicarle a cada `<article>` un [`scroll-margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-margin-top) mayor o igual al alto del menu.
En tu caso el menú mide `100px` de alto.

#### Ejemplo:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: lightgray;
}


/* Encabezado */

.sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

.sticky__header {
  background: #020230;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header img {
  height: 50px;
}

header a {
  color: #1cbeda;
}

.sticky__nav {
  background: #000;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.sticky__nav a {
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.sticky__nav a:hover {
  text-decoration: solid underline;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}


/* Cuerpo */

main {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 6px;
}

article {
  scroll-margin-top: 100px;
}

section {
  margin-right: 100px;
  width: 80%;
}

aside {
  padding: 5px;
  height: 400px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 170px;
  width: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 0 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav h2 {
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

.navigation__ul {
  border-left: 1px solid #a1a0a0;
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.navigation__ul-li {
  padding: 15px;
}

.navigation__ul-li a {
  color: #4e4e4e;
}

.navigation__ul-li a:hover {
  color: #0085f2;
}


/* Pie de pagina */

footer {
  background: #020230;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #808080cb;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #5e5c5c;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-co">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="icon" href="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ImN3cWvQ-hLJEbSI-l-aWQAAAA?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Maquetado</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="sticky">
    <header class="sticky__header">
      <a href="index.html"><img src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/OIP.ImN3cWvQ-hLJEbSI-l-aWQAAAA?rs=1&pid=ImgDetMain" alt="icono-web"></a>
      <a href="index.html">
        <h1>Guía de la web</h1>
      </a>
    </header>
    <nav class="sticky__nav">
      <a href="#html">HTML</a>
      <a href="#css">CSS</a>
      <a href="#javascript">JAVASCRIPT</a>
    </nav>
  </div>

  <h2>Recursos para desarrolladores &#128187</h2>
  <main>
    <section>
      <article id="html">
        <h3>html</h3>
        <p>Es el componente más básico de la Web. Define el significado y la estructura del contenido web.Es un estándar que sirve de referencia del software que conecta con la elaboración de páginas web en sus diferentes versiones, define una estructura
          básica y un código (denominado código HTML) para la definición de contenido de una página web, como texto, imágenes, videos, juegos, entre otros.
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Totam nihil quia velit ea ut magni assumenda. Culpa adipisci dolores facilis ipsam! Unde fuga porro error labore assumenda soluta earum dolore?
                    Natus consectetur quo esse voluptatibus unde neque deserunt perspiciatis cum ab mollitia consequatur, fugit corporis voluptatem! In aliquid totam, nostrum voluptate sunt libero necessitatibus accusantium veniam nihil error, placeat magnam!
                    Ullam, accusamus error! Aliquam at nobis exercitationem cumque ut atque sequi nihil ex debitis provident odit, iusto molestiae expedita enim. Optio quos magnam debitis veniam amet quas dolores quaerat possimus.
                    Facilis, harum obcaecati sint tenetur corporis explicabo ducimus consectetur labore incidunt, eligendi hic voluptatibus exercitationem ex, ad beatae architecto? Atque rem reprehenderit voluptate non fugiat numquam iure, exercitationem harum sapiente.
                    Sint, doloribus harum. Mollitia voluptate accusantium maxime, debitis quis laborum similique fugiat aut eos quod expedita exercitationem sequi delectus. Voluptate iusto error architecto consectetur aperiam modi nesciunt aspernatur totam cumque. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit quod necessitatibus suscipit dignissimos, quas quia exercitationem natus. Officia eos esse magni, illum mollitia rem, illo eum id aliquid quis facere.
                    In incidunt asperiores nulla iusto temporibus! Quidem illum eum, cum expedita aliquam rerum molestiae. Nemo autem odio error odit officia illum beatae maxime. Ducimus ex rem repellat atque quibusdam officia?
                    Ex, amet vero accusantium ullam dignissimos, voluptatum quia autem voluptatibus voluptates obcaecati odio soluta assumenda cupiditate! Cupiditate, eveniet! Ab fugiat voluptate suscipit explicabo ducimus saepe quibusdam sed, id sequi non!
                    Iusto eius eos odio ipsum vero ducimus quam! Sit harum, necessitatibus voluptatem tenetur ut voluptatibus assumenda libero, officiis neque, praesentium sint totam id minus quisquam. Delectus minus nihil ratione error.
                    Ut earum accusantium aliquam laudantium! Error, consequatur corporis? Voluptatem, quaerat. Quos, iure odit non, maxime repellat minima blanditiis minus sapiente ipsum quod id nostrum quidem culpa ea! Quia, perspiciatis distinctio! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorem eius ullam, illum quam rem voluptate aut quae dicta quis reprehenderit animi fugiat at soluta, natus cumque molestias laborum magnam quaerat!
                    Velit blanditiis aspernatur quos delectus! Expedita ipsa quisquam quidem ipsum libero animi error nihil eius veritatis itaque, excepturi saepe dolor quos cum maiores vitae ut culpa? Voluptas est ad ab!
                    Aut voluptas, quas blanditiis aliquid, repudiandae impedit nesciunt neque sunt nam at atque aperiam corrupti voluptatum possimus necessitatibus? Possimus architecto omnis atque dignissimos labore eius provident consequuntur ab adipisci itaque.
                    Officiis facere odit cumque at harum, eos expedita aspernatur consequatur obcaecati laborum fugiat. Sunt quod iste tenetur harum quas pariatur amet, magnam alias iure fugiat dolorum sapiente reiciendis placeat. Vel?
                    Ullam facere, neque ipsum ratione facilis in laudantium quo dolorum iusto, consequuntur, voluptatem laborum mollitia quibusdam. Impedit, incidunt! Quasi neque doloremque quae id mollitia sint optio, aliquam veritatis corrupti veniam. Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi tenetur incidunt ratione illo, odit omnis consequatur ut ducimus placeat excepturi repellat. Quas, magnam! Sint, eius sunt laudantium similique suscipit totam.
                    Repudiandae, temporibus, sequi sint earum recusandae perferendis quia, nihil quaerat placeat optio unde modi amet. Totam aliquid tenetur eos optio explicabo quia saepe eius! Sed facere ea labore amet blanditiis?
                    Omnis magnam enim temporibus dicta doloribus excepturi tempora voluptas consequuntur ipsa assumenda? Aspernatur possimus dolor, sapiente quod repudiandae harum natus quidem voluptates dignissimos dolore id explicabo minima reprehenderit dolores iste!
                    Quia doloremque sed iste dignissimos, natus iure obcaecati rem impedit ipsum fugit mollitia corrupti ratione veritatis quidem nihil quos eum quae dolorum deleniti voluptatem quod earum omnis? Quia, aut laborum.
                    Autem debitis soluta exercitationem, iste iusto ipsa quae temporibus a? Ut maxime cupiditate adipisci? Provident quasi assumenda officia corrupti, excepturi commodi qui repellendus facere distinctio cum recusandae quaerat eius et?
                    In molestiae quidem quam est, vitae excepturi corporis non sapiente laborum, unde quis sint placeat sit aliquid. Rem expedita ullam nostrum repudiandae possimus, ducimus maiores, natus quidem dolor iure ipsa.
                    Ipsum quidem sequi cupiditate officia excepturi voluptatibus adipisci vero deserunt esse minus, expedita libero nihil aut nostrum doloremque incidunt ab praesentium delectus ipsa. Modi iusto eius deserunt. Vel, soluta magni!</span>
        </p>
      </article>
      <article id="css">
        <h3>css</h3>
        <p>Es un lenguaje de diseño gráfico para definir y crear la presentación de un documento estructurado escrito en un lenguaje de marcado.Es muy usado para establecer el diseño visual de los documentos web, e interfaces de usuario escritas en HTML
          o XHTML; el lenguaje puede ser aplicado a cualquier documento XML, incluyendo XHTML, SVG, XUL, RSS, etcétera. Junto con HTML y JavaScript, CSS es una tecnología usada por muchos sitios web para crear páginas visualmente atractivas, interfaces
          de usuario para aplicaciones web y GUIs para muchas aplicaciones móviles
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Similique aperiam facilis, excepturi reprehenderit, distinctio dolor temporibus qui magnam et alias explicabo eligendi libero. Culpa at nulla architecto veniam omnis perferendis.
                    Ex nostrum eligendi sunt mollitia amet, inventore pariatur impedit, voluptatibus consectetur quae a placeat, repellendus iure velit dolorem excepturi atque id voluptatem porro eum quia accusantium ullam! Iure, quod nemo.
                    Et libero commodi illo tempora omnis perspiciatis fuga impedit ducimus porro laborum! Magnam soluta eligendi quam itaque aut incidunt suscipit, odio numquam inventore blanditiis tempore id, officiis nostrum! Modi, ipsa?
                    Dolorum incidunt aperiam ducimus, nesciunt exercitationem ad sequi dignissimos natus enim aliquid nisi repellendus facere autem repudiandae mollitia expedita velit dolorem eligendi harum molestias odio quos? Illum itaque possimus voluptates?
                    Praesentium suscipit laborum nihil animi, reiciendis quisquam magnam repudiandae soluta ad hic obcaecati quos dolores nemo quia debitis quo tenetur aut error necessitatibus ab architecto sed deleniti illo eligendi. Numquam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga totam repellendus obcaecati error, placeat sequi quisquam perferendis nostrum sed nobis esse et enim, quam porro alias excepturi. Maxime, praesentium temporibus.
                    Labore ex cum a aliquam reprehenderit architecto doloremque possimus ab, dolorem rem doloribus. Sapiente fugiat numquam maxime repellat, aut animi, ab fugit dicta illo ipsam, similique recusandae saepe qui minus!
                    Soluta debitis perferendis dignissimos distinctio eaque saepe repellendus eius quas aliquid ea! Magnam fugit perspiciatis magni beatae minima, ratione sit ipsam itaque omnis! Facilis ipsum nostrum, atque similique quasi sed!
                    Nulla, placeat, aut excepturi accusamus quidem non eaque commodi facilis possimus aspernatur eos tempora, minus in. Molestias non laborum laboriosam qui doloribus? Qui vero iure totam nemo ipsum, laboriosam corporis!
                    Veniam, voluptatibus error molestias dignissimos aut tenetur, porro aliquam rem sit, nobis voluptates vel facilis harum illum enim id! Repellat alias architecto aspernatur vel facilis quam debitis corrupti quaerat facere! Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Maiores neque perferendis dolores natus expedita voluptatum dolor, amet delectus reprehenderit, dicta, cumque deleniti laboriosam nemo similique necessitatibus iure architecto! Perspiciatis, illo!
                    Corporis, sapiente. Earum minus deleniti quasi natus laudantium sit, enim nihil totam consectetur. Magnam ratione impedit doloremque asperiores sit laudantium at sunt nostrum. Itaque ipsum mollitia cumque. Odit, doloribus eligendi?
                    Ipsa nisi, sint sed excepturi voluptatum soluta ea tempore harum nostrum eos explicabo eligendi error quae cum numquam dolorem veniam fugiat iste inventore assumenda. Asperiores nisi vero quos alias suscipit!
                    Tempora non necessitatibus temporibus nemo obcaecati iste asperiores dicta rem soluta aliquid ullam expedita excepturi sint placeat sit ipsum corporis, at numquam repellendus, laudantium blanditiis in omnis. Placeat, quos quas?
                    Ullam nulla molestiae eveniet modi voluptates rerum doloremque assumenda sint dolores nihil, eum voluptate beatae numquam corporis obcaecati minima architecto molestias quidem autem saepe porro pariatur, veritatis consequatur. Ab, placeat? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, tempora qui voluptas, dolores quos ratione atque laboriosam doloribus id facilis officiis similique. Distinctio esse consequuntur porro, minima earum expedita quia.
                    Deleniti non tenetur ab, possimus reprehenderit soluta accusamus libero laudantium sint consequatur numquam. Adipisci quia assumenda consequuntur impedit, quae cupiditate libero, nihil ea illo earum eum fuga saepe odit! Aliquid.
                    Placeat corporis quam quaerat doloremque unde repellendus dolor natus rem porro ipsa nisi est esse dignissimos quas, corrupti officia quia quisquam odit voluptatibus quod. Veniam ut quo hic dolores nesciunt.
                    Officia quas accusantium, vitae animi, dicta quibusdam quae dolore quam, ipsa molestias quod unde itaque totam error? Veniam hic necessitatibus aliquam odio ex, esse debitis eaque repudiandae. A, temporibus inventore?
                    Eligendi praesentium non voluptatum modi molestias illo dolorum. Odio voluptatibus eligendi placeat tempora repudiandae unde odit facere nemo ipsa corporis? Dolore doloribus vero vitae labore placeat dolor amet culpa molestiae.
                    Molestiae inventore, eaque aliquam id quas maxime nemo, quisquam blanditiis voluptatibus, nostrum repellendus. Perspiciatis harum tempora quos inventore, ducimus aut eum labore perferendis necessitatibus nostrum enim! Asperiores, libero! Eligendi, earum?
                    Cupiditate excepturi dolorem consequuntur delectus facere, ad vel odio beatae soluta! Officiis perferendis cumque impedit minima sint laboriosam quo repudiandae totam saepe ex? Tenetur, porro unde consectetur accusantium quaerat itaque!</span>
        </p>
      </article>
      <article id="javascript">
        <h3>JavaScript</h3>
        <p>Es un lenguaje de programación interpretado, dialecto del estándar ECMAScript. Se define como orientado a objetos, basado en prototipos, imperativo, débilmente tipado y dinámico. Se utiliza principalmente del lado del cliente, implementado como
          parte de un navegador web permitiendo mejoras en la interfaz de usuario y páginas web dinámicas y JavaScript del lado del servidor.
          <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Harum praesentium expedita nemo. A voluptatem facilis veniam accusantium ut hic iusto quidem est rerum, pariatur tempore maxime cum iure quo omnis?
                    Nesciunt aliquid repellendus corporis doloribus maiores nulla numquam, maxime impedit velit vitae nam voluptatem id fugiat totam qui optio commodi amet non corrupti quisquam voluptates consectetur, illum praesentium? Excepturi, natus!
                    Minima obcaecati a perspiciatis libero rem, ad deserunt porro, molestiae ab, at doloribus accusamus aspernatur veniam tempora odit praesentium id. Fugiat saepe impedit ipsam obcaecati corrupti delectus at sequi nemo!
                    Culpa voluptas id repellendus voluptatum et minus deleniti sunt adipisci suscipit atque! Exercitationem praesentium voluptate rerum hic facere, inventore unde sed dolorum assumenda odit quos quibusdam ratione impedit harum. Cum?
                    Nostrum eaque aut atque placeat doloribus maxime unde, ducimus nam quaerat id corporis, reiciendis nulla! Excepturi harum quisquam corporis odit quo? Cupiditate illo dolore accusantium ab quos repellat quo aperiam! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque harum aliquid ex nesciunt enim ad qui incidunt provident adipisci, ratione perferendis, ipsa tenetur, dignissimos odio cupiditate unde tempora labore quae.
                    Architecto numquam alias ullam repellendus, adipisci officia impedit facilis dicta et! Voluptates aperiam magni ad a enim, aspernatur quisquam corrupti architecto fugiat quia iure minima tenetur aliquid optio. Cum, voluptates!
                    Neque obcaecati asperiores deleniti sequi sapiente voluptatem expedita provident amet facere omnis qui eos, hic tenetur ducimus culpa odit, voluptatum aperiam adipisci quas nesciunt perferendis voluptates? Unde animi debitis ullam?
                    Quis temporibus nobis possimus nemo voluptatum odio! Maxime rerum neque odio ducimus natus fugiat animi expedita, explicabo quaerat ipsum nemo aperiam laudantium quos dignissimos odit quae ullam doloribus fuga aliquam.
                    Sunt debitis labore fugiat recusandae neque amet odit tempore sed aliquam commodi doloremque at provident laudantium voluptas, quasi aut laboriosam placeat aperiam. Illum modi, minus repudiandae explicabo iure distinctio eaque. Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reprehenderit nulla iste earum perspiciatis similique iure dolorum ad officiis ratione consectetur doloribus temporibus, explicabo, delectus, dicta eveniet eos in odit expedita.
                    Aut blanditiis perspiciatis ipsum, rem temporibus hic debitis possimus repellendus esse dolores delectus sapiente animi sed qui, neque sint tenetur, consequuntur eum sequi odit? Eum tenetur possimus accusantium corporis officiis!
                    A molestiae expedita, id officia ipsum aliquam in nemo quibusdam sit. Repellendus fugit ullam mollitia tempora adipisci impedit molestias tenetur harum quasi quae, cum ipsam quos, itaque error minus a!
                    Voluptate sit corrupti magni fuga voluptatum autem numquam vel repudiandae voluptatibus, totam modi! Accusantium ut nam alias error explicabo odit, magni eveniet laboriosam enim earum doloremque dolorum libero, nemo odio.
                    Reprehenderit aspernatur fuga aliquam facere, reiciendis minus tempora blanditiis sed, expedita optio mollitia nostrum nam iste sunt eaque dolor sint saepe illum magni. Dicta eos culpa minus ab quos autem. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Ea explicabo odit culpa est minima ipsum eius dolores esse doloremque, libero, sint totam iste voluptatem, cupiditate voluptates temporibus optio quos vero?
                    Debitis, error. Odit, deserunt. Tempora obcaecati consequatur nulla quaerat harum placeat dolor! Modi, beatae? Cumque adipisci explicabo ea autem odio possimus fugit vero! Fuga velit beatae totam, molestias aperiam voluptate!
                    Tempore quisquam rerum cum magnam hic ratione accusantium laudantium cumque excepturi molestiae! Aut labore repellendus earum quos, eos voluptate dignissimos! Debitis impedit sint, repudiandae ab excepturi laboriosam quasi voluptatum dolore!
                    Quasi accusantium laudantium error aut tempore nisi atque provident corporis, et doloremque a harum in! Excepturi, nisi necessitatibus quo reprehenderit earum magni, molestiae laboriosam totam ea reiciendis consequuntur nemo cumque.
                    Nihil voluptas quod unde aspernatur. Illo minus delectus hic dolore dolores. Qui quae dolorem, ad recusandae magnam, odit nam perferendis libero, et ratione asperiores illum voluptates nobis vitae eius natus?
                    Consectetur repudiandae earum mollitia, dicta id facilis dolorum minus dignissimos laborum temporibus, aliquid et dolores similique magni ab commodi! Est, facere officia similique reiciendis asperiores odio magnam deleniti dolorem animi.
                    Similique facere eius, a velit voluptatum, minus qui sapiente, culpa laudantium assumenda dolorem. Quo repudiandae quia accusantium tenetur labore pariatur vel minima. Distinctio placeat accusantium voluptatibus. Officiis eveniet possimus magnam.</span>
        </p>
      </article>
    </section>

    <aside>
      <nav>
        <h2>En este articulo</h2>
        <div class="navigation">
          <ul class="navigation__ul">
            <li class="navigation__ul-li"><a href="#html">HTML</a></li>
            <li class="navigation__ul-li"><a href="#css">CSS</a></li>
            <li class="navigation__ul-li"><a href="#javascript">JAVASCRIPT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </aside>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>Esta pagina es una prueba</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```